# How to perform search based on more that one values in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, simpleadapter

I am using AutoCompleteTextView for searching City. I am using Array Adapter for binding AutoCompleteTextView. Now I want to enter either City or Zip Code on AutoCompleteTextView and want List of Cities based on that. How can I do it?

Comment: Implement a custom adapter for the `AutocompleTextView` thatreturns a custom `Filter` from the `getFilter()` method. In that `Filter`, in its `performFiltering()` method, look at the constraint you get passed in and check if it's a string(which will most likely be a city name) or if it's a number(which I assume will be a number). Based on that knowledge filter the results. Also, extending `BaseAdapter` is more appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can yse NameFilter in ArrayAdapter:

```
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return nameFilter;
        }

        Filter cityFilter = new Filter() {
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                String str = ((YourObject) (resultValue)).getName();
                return str;
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            //Your code for find CIty by name or zip 
        }

           @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                //You can now update youArrayList and after you need call notifyDataSetChanged
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            };
```